# MYSQL REGEXP operation

Tags: mysql, sql

I saw this part of MySQL query code in the Project I handle. The code was coded 5 years ago.

```
CAST((CASE
    WHEN cat.title REGEXP "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" THEN LEFT(cat.title,4)
    WHEN cat.title REGEXP "^[0-9][0-9][0-9]" THEN LEFT(cat.title,3)
    WHEN cat.title REGEXP "^[0-9][0-9]" THEN LEFT(cat.title,2)
    WHEN cat.title REGEXP "^[0-9]" THEN LEFT(cat.title,1)
ELSE NULL END) AS SIGNED) int_cat,
IF((CASE
    WHEN cat.title REGEXP "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" THEN LEFT(cat.title,4)
    WHEN cat.title REGEXP "^[0-9][0-9][0-9]" THEN LEFT(cat.title,3)
    WHEN cat.title REGEXP "^[0-9][0-9]" THEN LEFT(cat.title,2)
    WHEN cat.title REGEXP "^[0-9]" THEN LEFT(cat.title,1)
ELSE NULL END) IS NULL, cat.title, NULL) int_cat_string,
```

can someone explain how this query working? what is the usage of `REGEXP` and `THEN LEFT`
I want to refactor this code. I just a hard time thinking this area of QUERY.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words it searches for the first positions and expect to be numbers between 0-9.

> "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" ---> first 4 positions
>
> "^[0-9][0-9][0-9]" ---> first 3 positions
>
> "^[0-9][0-9]" ---> first 2 positions
>
> "^[0-9]" ---> first position

Follow below example:

```
create table cat (
title varchar(20));

insert into cat values ('ab2cd978'),('1bg54g78g'),('102578'),('aa45'),('123'); 

select title,case WHEN cat.title REGEXP "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" THEN LEFT(cat.title,4) end as nr4,
             case  WHEN cat.title REGEXP "^[0-9][0-9][0-9]" THEN LEFT(cat.title,3) end as nr3 ,
             case WHEN cat.title REGEXP "^[0-9][0-9]" THEN LEFT(cat.title,2) end as nr2,
             case WHEN cat.title REGEXP "^[0-9]" THEN LEFT(cat.title,1) end as nr1
 from cat
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> title       nr4    nr3    nr2   nr1
> ab2cd978    null   null   null  null              
> 1bg54g78g   null   null   null   1
> 102578      1025   102    10     1
> aa45        null   null   null  null      
> 123         null   123    12     1
> ```

The results for the value ab2cd978  are all null because any of the condition isn't true, any of the  4 first positions isn't a number  between 0-9

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-regular-expression-regexp.aspx